# Is it possible to do deep clone of httpservletrequest and how?

Tags: clone

I am trying to do deep clone of httpservletRequest object so that I have copy of all referenced objects in order to use it my business logic. Can I make deep clone of httpservletRequest ? any implementation Idea will be great!

Thanks